# How to control vertical placement of text next to an image in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I need help with controlling the position of my text, which is next to an image.

This is what my current code is rendering:

[image]

This is my goal:

[image]

```css
  .content-selfmade{
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #111019;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    float:left;
    color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: .2em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .content-selfmade-name{
    top: 0;
  }
  #steam-photo{
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/fkue1Ww.png');
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="content-selfmade">
  <img id="steam-photo" src="http://i.imgur.com/fkue1Ww.png">
  <span class="content-selfmade-name">Audun</span>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wpwpq4gq/

Comment: which position?

Comment: you want move your text to where?

Comment: "How can I move my text up to this position?" - what is "this position"?

Comment: I wasn't able to post any code or images somehow..,

Comment: You most certainly can post code. You made no effort to do so. Please take some time to read through the [help], particularly [ask] and [How to Create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are you closing the `<img>` with a `</span>`?

Comment: I can't edit your question now, please improve your description to make it clear to the community.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it in a specified position, use this CSS Code.

```
position: absolute;
top: 100px;
left: 50px;
```

You can set the Y axis with top property and X axis with left property.

Or, if you want to use margins, here's my tip.

Sometimes you can specify the pixels in negatively. E.g.,

```
margin-top: -30px;
```

I suggest the second way to make a flexible website as if you'll use absolute position, you'll need to make the whole website using it and you'll need to make different websites for different-sized devices to make it look good.

The choice is in your hand.